# Why does WinSCP use a .com binary for the CLI version and an .exe binary for the GUI?

Tags: windows-10, ms-dos, winscp

I thought .com is an ancient form for executable, leftover from early MS-DOS days? Why do they use that today in WinSCP? And why only for the CLI version?

I tried asking this in their chat room, but received not a single reply for days. As always.

Answer (score 4):

Both WinSCP files are actually regular Win32 executables in the standard Windows PE format.

(Windows does not actually require the format to match the extension – as long as the shell detects that it is *a* known "executable" extension, it'll simply tell the OS to execute it, and the OS kernel itself will take care of format specifics.)

However, when Windows Cmd.exe searches %PATH% for a matching executable, it does so in the order specified by the %PATHEXT% environment variable – which lists `.COM` *before* `.EXE`.

So if you simply type `winscp` in Cmd, then the command shell will prefer to run `winscp.com` (which is the CLI tool) instead of `winscp.exe` (which is graphical).

Comment: Yes that's correct. For additional information, see also [Executables `winscp.exe` and `winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables). + Btw, it's inspired by Visual Studio [`devenv.com`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches) and `devenv.exe`.